# Fields error and globalerrors stay empty in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am currently using the following code in a project, the issue I have is that even when there are errors in the bindingresult (bindingResult.hasErrors() is true), it's rendered false in the thymeleaf result. This makes me think the bindingResult isn't "injected" correctly. Did I do anything wrong in the following code?

```
<form action="blog.html" th:action="@{/fileUpload}" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${form}">
        <input type="text" name="title" th:field="*{title}" /> <input
                type="text" name="content" th:field="*{content}" /> <input
                type="file" name="myFile" th:field="*{myFile}" /> <input
                type="submit" />

        <div id="errors" class="alert alert-error">
                <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
                </ul>

                <div th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}">
                        <p th:each="err : ${#fields.globalErrors()}" th:text="${err}">...</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blog", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndex(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new AddBlogForm());
        return "blog";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String importParse(Model model, @Valid AddBlogForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        try {
                if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                        model.addAttribute("successmessage", "Succesfully added");
                        blogSrv.addPost(form.getTitle(), form.getContent(), form.getMyFile());
                        model.addAttribute("form", new AddBlogForm());
                }
                return "blog";
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IllegalStateException occured " + e.getMessage()));
                return "blog";
        } catch (IOException e) {
                bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IOException occured " + e.getMessage()));
                return "blog";
        }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `Model` attribute and add `@ModelAttribute` to your `AddBlogForm` method argument. On succesful save redirect to your `/blog` URL. (Post-redirect-get is a very common thing to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to work around Springs data binding, work with the framework.

First remove the `Model` attribute from your method signature, second use a redirect after a successful save, and finally add `@ModelAttribute` to your `AddBlogForm` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String importParse(@Valid @ModelAttribute AddBlogForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    try {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            blogSrv.addPost(form.getTitle(), form.getContent(), form.getMyFile());
            return "redirect:/blog";
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IllegalStateException occured " + e.getMessage()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IOException occured " + e.getMessage()));
    }
    return "blog"
}
```

If you really want to add a success message to the model, use `RedirectAttributes` instead and use a flash message so that it is available after the redirect.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String importParse(@Valid @ModelAttribute AddBlogForm form, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes attrs) {
    try {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            atts.setFlashAttribute("successmessage", "Succesfully added");
            blogSrv.addPost(form.getTitle(), form.getContent(), form.getMyFile());
            return "redirect:/blog";
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IllegalStateException occured " + e.getMessage()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("image", "IOException occured " + e.getMessage()));
    }
    return "blog"
}
```